# wget failure in docker container and seems http proxy doesn't work in Centos 7.3

Tags: docker, wget, centos7, http-proxy

I met an issue: wget failure in docker container (CentOS 7.3). I seached related solution in network, and tried them, but "wget" still doesn't work.

How to debug the issue? Anybody can help me?
Thanks

Detail steps as bellow:

1. install docker-ce 17.06.0 on CentOS 7.3
2. set http_proxy in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`
3. flush changese: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
4. restart Docker: `sudo systemctl restart docker`
5. run a container
6. in the container, ping http proxy is successful, but 'wget' failure in the docker container.
7. try to set proxy in `/etc/default/docker`, `/etc/sysconfig/docker` and even start dockerd with http proxy. But still failure

========================================================================

```
[root@nettra ~]# docker info|grep Proxy 
WARNING: overlay: the backing xfs filesystem is formatted without d_type  support, which leads to incorrect behavior.
Reformat the filesystem with ftype=1 to enable d_type support.
Running without d_type support will not be supported in future  releases. 
Http Proxy: http://135.245.48.34:8000/ 
Https Proxy: http://135.245.48.34:8000/ 
No Proxy:localhost,localhost.localdomain,127.0.0.1,135.1.29.42,135.251.50.10
[root@nettra ~]#
```

run "wget" in host ==> successfully (by proxy 135.245.48.34:8000)

```
[root@nettra ~]# wget http_xxx
--2017-07-25 12:33:23--  http_xxx
Connecting to 135.245.48.34:8000... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-sh]
Saving to: ‘homer_installer.sh.1’

    [  <=>                                                                            
] 32,671       124KB/s   in 0.3s

2017-07-25 12:33:26 (124 KB/s) - ‘homer_installer.sh.1’ saved [32671]

[root@nettra ~]#
```

but run "wget" in container ==> failure (it seems proxy doesn't work) [root@nettra ~]# docker run -i -t test /bin/bash

```
[root@dc95e2dc1597 /]# wget http_xxx
--2017-07-25 04:38:38--  http_xxx
Resolving cdn.rawgit.com (cdn.rawgit.com)... 198.232.125.81
Connecting to cdn.rawgit.com (cdn.rawgit.com)|198.232.125.81|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

ping http proxy ==> successfully

```
[root@dc95e2dc1597 /]# ping 135.245.48.34
PING 135.245.48.34 (135.245.48.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 135.245.48.34: icmp_seq=1 ttl=237 time=267 ms
64 bytes from 135.245.48.34: icmp_seq=2 ttl=237 time=252 ms
64 bytes from 135.245.48.34: icmp_seq=3 ttl=237 time=252 ms
64 bytes from 135.245.48.34: icmp_seq=4 ttl=237 time=252 ms
^C
--- 135.245.48.34 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 252.072/255.956/267.068/6.448 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a `/etc/wgetrc` file in the container with proxy information as below:

```
use_proxy = on
http_proxy =  http://username:password@proxy.server.address:port/
https_proxy =  http://username:password@proxy.server.address:port/
ftp_proxy =  http://username:password@proxy.server.address:port/
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are confused with environment variables to set in container with environment variables used by Docker ,for example environment variable to set proxy server to pull image from registry behind proxy.

In first case, you can set env variables in Dockerfile itself using ENV

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://192.168.1.12:3128",
     "httpsProxy": "http://192.168.1.12:3128",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com,127.0.0.0/8"
   }
 }
}
```

All containers started by this user will have these environment variables.
Thanks
instruction or you can use docker client config in file ~/.docker/config.json